# Android Navigation Drawer abstraction

Tags: android, inheritance, layout, abstraction

I know this question has been asked before (2 other i found similar) but they didnt address this side of the scenario!

SO here's the scenario, I created a class as this:

```
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

  // Implemeted the Actionbar and navigation drawer here!
  // and it containts onCreate method and setContentView
}
```

BaseActivity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/base_nav_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/base_left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#dddddd"/>
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/base_right_drawer"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#dddddd"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

then extended my main class/activity from it:

```
public class Main extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
```

and here's Main activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:id="@+id/stream_new_layout"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="hi dude"/>    
</LinearLayout>
```

so now i can see the Actionbar and Navigation drawer in my Main activity, however, if i try to use `setContectView(R.layout.main)` on my Main activity to use the xml layout i created specific to this activity, the nav drawer will no show up anymore; i guess because `onCreate` and `setContectView` on Main activity, overrides the same statements from BaseActivity which i extended from. any solution for this?

Comment: Could you post the full implementation of the onCreate method of those 2 Activities? I cannot imagine the ActionBar completely disappeasing ...

Comment: my bad! actionbar appears. only nav drawer does not work/show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood you right: You are using `setContentView()` in your `BaseActivity` to set up the drawer and `setContentView()` in your `MainActivity` to do the rest of your layout setup? 
If thats the case: it won't work that way. The second time you do `setContentView()` it will replace the old layout and then there's no more drawer. 
You got to have a drawer in the layout that you use in `setContentView()` in your `MainActivity`. 
Also, son't use `setContentView()` twice, the first time is useless.

Comment: so to be clear, i shouldnt use "setContentView()" in my BaseActivity, and, i have to use that BaseActivity XML that i posted above, as my Main activity's xml layout?

Comment: Yes, try that. If you want to have a drawer, there has to be one in the layout that you use in your MainActivity, yes.